# unique value of a column and converting it to a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataFrame

```
Serial N       voltage       current
   B              10            nan
   B              10            nan
   C              12            nan
   D              40            nan
   .               .             .
   AB             12            nan
```

I would like to get a list of serial N as a list and not a Factor.

I did something like this

```
temp=unique(df$Serial_N)
```

but I get a factor. How can I convert it to a list such that I can loop though it or access an serial N I want from it like

```
temp[[1]]
```

Comment: How about `temp <- unique(as.character(df$Serial_N))`? It will be a vector, not a list. You can access as `temp[1]` etc..

Comment: that works perfect